# What's a good setup to work with multiple Play version?

Tags: playframework

I now have a few different projects using different Play versions, and I need to context switch between them constantly.

What's a good setup for my Windows machine?

1. Should I add both folders to PATH and rename play.bat to play1 and play2 ? Does the order between the libs matter?
2. Should I prepare a batch script that switches my path variable?

Has anyone does this and can recommend a working setup?
Specifically I'm using 1.2.4 and 2.1.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first approach should work as expected, I'm using similar approach on my unix stations/servers but with usage of symlinks in `/usr/bin` ie: `play200`, `play204`, `play210` etc.

Of course for most recent version you can keep just a `play` :)

Answer (score 2):

You should give it a try to [Play Version Manager](https://github.com/kaiinkinen/pvm). I know that is for Unix/Linux systems but I think it deserves the extra computer configuration effort is you cannot change your OS.